# Une citation chaque jour

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange

Bonjour,

J'ai découvert ce Stack il y a quelques temps et je me demandais pourquoi ne metterions-nous pas une citation en Français sur la page d'accueil chaque jour. Les utilisateurs pourraient y contribuer et en proposer.

Comment: Je suis pour ! Cela animera encore un peu plus ce Stack !!

Comment: @ThomasGuénet Savez-vous qui contacter pour essayer de mettre cela en place ?